# Get substring with RegEx

Tags: c#, regex

I am really struggling with RegEx. I want my RegEx (if possible) to do 2 things:

1- Validate that the whole string respects the format **NAME_STKBYGRP.CSV**

2- Extract the **NAME** substring if match

Examples:

```
TEST_STKBYGRP.CSV -> TEST
other_stkbygrp.csv -> other
test_wrong.csv -> ""
```

Here is what I tried so far

```
string input = "NAME_STKBYGRP.CSV";
Regex regex = new Regex("([A-Z])*_STKBYGRP.CSV", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
string s = regex.Match(input).Value;
```

It does return `""` if it doesn't match but return the whole `input` if it matches.

Comment: How would the second example return when "other" is not upper case?

Comment: @juharr I used `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to read `regex.Match(input).Groups[1].Value` if you only want the value of the first group.

You should also add a `^` and `$` at the start and end of your regex if you want to rule out strings like `evilnumber12345_NAME_STKBYGRP.CSVevilsuffix`.

Edit: [adv12](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1771817/adv12) also has [a good point](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36502452/215380) about the location of the `*` - it should be inside the parentheses.

Comment: If he puts a `$` then he should even anchor the `^`... and he should escape the `.`...

Comment: @xanatos Good point, thanks, I'd forgotten the opening `*` isn't `.*`.

Comment: Other way: `@"^([A-Z])*(?=_STKBYGRP\.CSV$)"`

Answer (score 3):

First off, your `*` should be inside the parentheses.  Otherwise, you'll capture several single-character groups.  Then, use `Match.Groups[1]` to get just the characters matched by the portion of the regex in the parentheses.

Comment: Good point about the star - but `Groups[0]` will be the whole match again.

Comment: @Rawling, you're right; `Groups[0]` should have been `Groups[1]`.  I've edited my answer.